# "Marked as duplicate" and "possible duplicate"

Tags: discussion

When looking at [How to find out the end url upon redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749343/how-to-find-out-the-end-url-upon-redirection?rq=1), I noticed that the question has been marked as a duplicate but at the top of the thread, it states that it's a "Possible Duplicate"

Shouldn't the following be displayed at the top of the thread instead?

[image]

Comment: @Tunaki Oh, I see. I'm guessing that with the new system, it does do what I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39181613/1743880) for example (first one I found while searching for recent questions closed as duplicate)

Comment: `“Marked as duplicate” and “possible duplicate” [duplicate]` I came here for that

Comment: Upvoted to stay.